# What is the difference between Symantic error and Logical error in C?

Tags: c

1.

```
   int a=6, b=5, c;
        a + b = c;
        printf("%d", c);
        return 0;
```

2.

```
int calculateAreaRectangle(int height, int width)
    {
     return (height + width);
    }
```

which is symentic error and which is logical error?

My another question - Is it correct that symantic error is always detected during due to compilation? Please give some example.

Comment: A syntactic error is an error in the syntax, like using `[` instead of `{`. A semantic error is when you use a type wrong, like passing an `int` value to a function expecting a `char *`. A logic error is an error in the program logic, like you say "do A" when you really mean "do B".

Comment: This seems to be explained in more than 1 stackoverflow question. For example, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849684/what-is-semantic-errors-in-c-language-give-some-examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is semantic errors in C-language & give some examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849684/what-is-semantic-errors-in-c-language-give-some-examples)

Answer (score 1):

First is syntax error, and second is logic.

Think of a program like a sentence. Let the sentence be "I am goes to river to sleep". Here "goes" is syntax (grammar) error, and you see it right away. And your teacher (compiler) gives error. But "sleeping in river" is logic error. One could sleep in river but that would be meaningless.

So, your function promises to return area of a rectangle but does something else. And that is logic error.

Answer (score 1):

A **syntax** error, which you refer to as a semantic error (symentic? - it's the same as logical so I'm guessing you meant syntax) is just a straight typo (like writing mether instead of mother). A programming language is a strict language, that must be understood by a compiler. A syntax error is writing the language (program) in a wrong way:

```
a + b = c;
```

is wrong, because in `C` such a syntax doesn't exist in the language. The compiler will confirm this.

A **logical error** is the worst kind - the big bug in your programs. A logical error is when you write your entire program properly, so the **compiler does not complain at all**, and **the program seems to run and gives results, but the results are just wrong**! As you know, the area of a rectangle is

```
width*height
```

but you have

```
return (height + width);
```

That's a logical (**semantic)** error - you're function will run and output a number, but it will be far from the right one.

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax** (or grammar) describes the *structure* of the program - what functions, statements, and expressions are supposed to look like.  For example, the syntax of a `for` loop<sup>1</sup> is

```
for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
```

Thus, a *syntax error* is an error in the structure of the program - you're missing a semicolon, or curly braces or parentheses are mismatched, you've misspelled a keyword, something like that.  A compiler is *required* to issue a diagnostic<sup>2</sup> for syntax errors.

However, syntax alone cannot specify rules like "a variable must be declared before use", or "the target of an assignment must be a modifiable lvalue", or "the source and target of an assignment must be compatible types", etc.  **Semantic rules** (the C standard calls them *constraints*) describe what program constructs are *meaningful* - just because a statement is syntactically valid doesn't mean it's semantically meaningful.  For example, here's part of the syntax for a declaration:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiersopt
    function-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
    alignment-specifier declaration-specifiersopt
```

Now, based on syntax alone, we could come up with any arbitrary combination of type specifiers, type qualifiers, etc.  The *syntax* allows something like

```
int char long short unsigned double float foo;
```

but there are additional *constraints* that specify which combinations of type specifiers are meaningful.  `long long` and `long double` and `unsigned short int` are meaningful.  `double char` and `float long int` are not.

Thus, a *semantic error* (or a *constraint violation*) is an error in the *meaning* of the program - you're missing a declaration somewhere, or you're trying to assign to something that should not be written to, stuff like that.  Like with syntax errors, the compiler is *required* to issue a diagnostic for constraint violations.

So, is `a + b = c;` a syntax error or a semantic error?  Here's the syntax for assignment:

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression

assignment-operator: one of
    = *= /= %= += -= >= &= ^= |=
```

Does `a + b` reduce to a *unary-expression*? Based on my reading of the syntax, it does:

```
additive-expression:
    multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression + multiplicative-expression
    additive-expression - multiplicative-expression

multiplicative-expression:
    cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression * cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression / cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression % cast-expression

cast-expression:
    unary-expression
    ( type-name ) cast-expression
```

Here's how I see it reducing:

```
a + b =>
    additive-expression + multiplicative-expression =>
    additive-expression =>
    multiplicative-expression =>
    cast-expression =>
    unary-expression
```

So, at first blush, this doesn't appear to be a syntax error.  If it's not, it's *definitely* a semantic error (a.k.a. constraint violation), and that's how gcc reports it:

```
error: invalid lvalue in assignment
```

*lvalues* only come in to play at the semantic level, not the syntax level.  The result of `a + b` is not an lvalue - it doesn't correspond to a location that you can write a new value to, thus it cannot be the target of an assignment.

A **logic error** (a.k.a. bug) is an error in the *implementation* of the program.  For example, your function to calculate the area of a rectangle is implemented incorrectly.  *Sometimes*, logic errors trigger a constraint violation, but not always.  This is why you test.

---

1. [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

   The C language standard does not distinguish between "warnings" and "errors"; it only mandates that a diagnostic of some sort be issued for syntax errors and constraint violations.